# Update GoogleMaps Fragment with changes (or lack thereof)

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

My application has 5 fragments on a tab display, with one being a GoogleMaps Fragment that does work in displaying the map, a location blip of where the user is, and a camera update on that location. However, upon switching between fragments, **my location blip is lost**.

Here is my code, so I can better explain what I'm trying to do:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapView, mapFragment).commit();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    getDeviceLocation();

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }


}
```

I've tried to implement the `getDeviceLocation()`, `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, and the surrounding `if` case that's inside the onMapReady function right before the `onCreateView()` methods `return view;` line, but I get a null object reference error (on the `mMap` object) in the Logcat followed by a crash. This error **only** happens when moving those bits of code elsewhere: `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and `getDeviceLocation()`.

I assume it's because the mMap is still null until the view is retrieved. Basically, how can I keep the location blip maintained from calling the `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` method without running into the null error reference? Because it doesn't seem like I can implement the location-getting code anywhere that's before `return view` without getting a null error.

Sorry for the bad formatting and the lengthy question. I just can't figure out how to integrate the Google Maps API code with my own plans, so I'd greatly appreciate **any input** you guys have to offer.